# MOSFET alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, circuitikz

I'm unable to align the MOSFET vertically. I want the gate terminal to be vertical.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,4) to[battery1] (0,0);
            \draw (-0.5,2) node[left]{$V_\mathrm{in}$};
            \draw (0,4) to[short] (1,4);
            \draw (1,4) node[nigfete]{};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

\end{figure}

Comment: welcome to te tex.se. what you mean that gate is vertical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (1,4) node[nigfete, rotate=90] (fet) {}
        (fet.G) to [battery1, l_=$V_\mathrm{in}$] (fet.G |- 0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

or this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (1,4) node[nigfete] (fet) {}
        (fet.G) to [battery1, l_=$V_\mathrm{in}$] (fet.G |- 0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (fet.G |- 0,0) what is this for?

Comment: it determines coordinate below gate, which is horizontally aligned with `(0,0)`.

Comment: I like your picture. I upvote you.